# Unpivot multiple columns not showing desire result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

```
Original
    RecordKey   Name Section1_Product   Section1_Code   Section2_Product   Section2_Code ......
    1           a         ff              22               
    2           b         gg              22
    3           c         hh              33


    RecordKey     Name      Section     Product      Code ......
    1               a           1         ff          22
    1               a           2
    2               b           1         gg          22
    2               b           2
    3               c           1         hh          22
    3               c           2
```

I am trying to unpivot the columns into rows. Some sections will have null value.

```
SELECT RecordKey
 ,Name
 ,'Num_of_Sections' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RecordKey ORDER BY ID)
 ,Product
 ,Code
FROM (
SELECT RecordKey, Name, Section1_Product, Section1_Code, Section2_Product, Section2_Code FROM Table
) M

UNPITVOT (
  Product FOR ID IN (Section1_Product, Section2_Product)
) p

UNPIVOT (
  Code FOR CO IN (Section1_Code, Section2_Code)
) c
```

If I execute with only one column (Product, comment out Code) then I will have  2 values in ID column (1,2). If I run the query with 2 columns then I get 4 values in ID column(1, 2, 3, 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may as per my assumption and your data provided we can achieve this using Cross apply and Row_number

```
    declare @Record TABLE 
    ([RecordKey] int, 
    [Name] varchar(1), 
    [Section1_Product] varchar(2), 
    [Section1_Code] int, 
    [Section2_Product] varchar(2),
     [Section2_Code] int)
;

INSERT INTO @Record
    ([RecordKey], [Name], [Section1_Product], [Section1_Code],[Section2_Product],[Section2_Code])
VALUES
    (1, 'a', 'ff', 22,NULL,NULL),
    (2, 'b', 'gg', 22,NULL,NULL),
    (3, 'c', 'hh', 33,NULL,NULL)
;
    With cte as (
    Select T.RecordKey,
    T.Name,
    T.val,
    T.val1 from (
    select RecordKey,Name,val,val1 from @Record
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
                ('Section1_Product',Section1_Product),
                ('Section2_Product',Section2_Product))cs(col,val)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
                ('Section1_Code',Section1_Code),
                ('Section2_Code',Section2_Code))css(col1,val1)
    WHERE val is NOT NULL)T
    )
Select  c.RecordKey,
        c.Name,
        c.RN,
        CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN NULL ELSE c.val END Product,
        c.val1 Code 
            from (
Select RecordKey,
        Name,
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY val ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))RN,
        val,
        val1 from cte )C
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Section2_Product & Section2_Code can have values or can be null, and the file has more than 2 sections.

Comment: Just add the values in NULL Place and add the section's and codes in Cross Apply just like 1 & 2 @user1804925